# How split and extract elements to get a new data.frame

Tags: r

I want to split a one column data.frame to form a new data.frame with two columns ,for example, thanks!I need a efficient way to solve because original data sets about 10Million rows

```
         V1
         AA-11-aa
         BB-22-bb
         CC-33-cc
         DD-44-dd
```

to become

```
         V2    V3
         AA11  aa
         BB22  bb
         CC33  cc
         DD44  dd
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Can you please show us what you have tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: Read it in with `fread` (from package data.table) and use `-` as a seperator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This achieves what you want

```
mydf <- data.frame(V1=c("AA-11-aa", "BB-22-bb", "CC-33-cc", "DD-44-dd"))

strings <- unlist(strsplit(x=as.character(mydf$V1), split="-"))
n <- nrow(mydf)
data.frame(V1=paste(strings[seq(1, length.out=n, by=3)], strings[seq(2, length.out=n,  by=3)], sep=""),
           V2=strings[seq(3, length.out=n, by=3)])
```

Comment: ,my original data sets is 1O Million rows ,so I think "n<-nrow(mydf)" is not efficient

Comment: I am not sure to understand. `nrow()` is similar to `length()`. There is no loop over the rows of the data frame. If these statements are slow `nrow()` is probably not the bottleneck.

Comment: `mydf[, c("V2", "V3")] <-  list(sub("-", "", substring(mydf$V1, 0, 5)),
                           substring(mydf$V1, 7, 9))` is indeed better if your "-" delimited fields have a fixed width.

Comment: ,this's my specific problem,would you help to fix it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050760/how-to-extract-elements-from-web-log-to-form-a-data-frame

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to use `substring` along with "data.table":

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf)
DT[, c("V2", "V3") := list(sub("-", "", substring(V1, 0, 5)),
                           substring(V1, 7, 9))]
DT
#          V1   V2 V3
# 1: AA-11-aa AA11 aa
# 2: BB-22-bb BB22 bb
# 3: CC-33-cc CC33 cc
# 4: DD-44-dd DD44 dd
```

Comment: Matho,actually,there is much more elements in V1 than I illustrate ,such as "AA-xx-xx-xx-...-11-aa",will substring still work?

Comment: @user2810161, Perhaps if you describe your problem more accurately, you'll get more meaningful responses.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050760/how-to-extract-elements-from-web-log-to-form-a-data-frame  that's my specific problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with regular expressions. It also works with the general case (`"AA-xx-xx-xx-...-11-aa"`):

```
transform(mydf, V2 = gsub("([A-Z]+).*\\-([0-9]+).*", "\\1\\2", V1),
                V3 = gsub(".*\\-([a-z]+)", "\\1", V1))
```

The result:

```
        V1   V2 V3
1 AA-11-aa AA11 aa
2 BB-22-bb BB22 bb
3 CC-33-cc CC33 cc
4 DD-44-dd DD44 dd
```

Comment: thank you!Actually, this is my real problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20050760/how-to-extract-elements-from-web-log-to-form-a-data-frame