# How to extract elements from web log to form a data.frame?

Tags: r

I have a weblog about 1 million rows ,and I want extract some Date,Time and Status to form a
new data.frame.

```
       V1
       2013-08-27 16:00:01 117.79.149.2 GET 200 0 0
       2013-08-27 16:00:02 117.79.149.2 GET 404 0 0
       2013-08-27 16:00:03 117.79.149.2 GET 200 0 0
       2013-08-27 16:00:04 117.79.149.2 GET 404 0 0
```

to become

```
       Date_Time              Status
       2013-08-27 16:00:01    200
       2013-08-27 16:00:02    404
       2013-08-27 16:00:03    200
       2013-08-27 16:00:04    404
```

I know how to extract the elements I need by following code

```
       temp<-unlist(strsplit(x," "))
       Date_Time<-paste(temp[1],temp[2])
       Status<-temp[5]
```

But I didn't know how to execute it row by row to get a new data.frame without "for" loop,
How can I use to sapply or lapply to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution based on regular expressions:

```
with(dat, data.frame(Date_Time = gsub("(.*\\:[0-9]+) .*", "\\1", V1),
                     Status = gsub(".*T ([0-9]+) .*", "\\1", V1)))

#             Date_Time Status
# 1 2013-08-27 16:00:01    200
# 2 2013-08-27 16:00:02    404
# 3 2013-08-27 16:00:03    200
# 4 2013-08-27 16:00:04    404
```

---

where `dat` is your data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(V1 = readLines(
  textConnection("2013-08-27 16:00:01 117.79.149.2 GET 200 0 0
2013-08-27 16:00:02 117.79.149.2 GET 404 0 0
2013-08-27 16:00:03 117.79.149.2 GET 200 0 0
2013-08-27 16:00:04 117.79.149.2 GET 404 0 0")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply`:

```
example <- c("asdf asdwer dsf cswe asd","asfdw ewr cswe sdf wers")  
split.example <- strsplit(example," ")
example.2 <- sapply(split.example,"[[",2)
```

This gives:

```
> example.2
[1] "asdwer" "ewr"
```

Just to make this a complete answer, using `dat` provided by @Sven:

```
temp <- strsplit(as.character(dat$V1)," ")
new.df <- data.frame(Date_Time = paste(sapply(temp,"[[",1),
                                       sapply(temp,"[[",2)),
                     Status = sapply(temp,"[[",5))

> new.df
            Date_Time Status
1 2013-08-27 16:00:01    200
2 2013-08-27 16:00:02    404
3 2013-08-27 16:00:03    200
4 2013-08-27 16:00:04    404
```

Comment: ,would you help me to solve this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093294/how-do-i-skip-sign-without-loop-while-extract-elements  THX in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
mydf <- data.frame(V1=c("2013-08-27 16:00:01 117.79.149.2 GET 200 0 0",
   "2013-08-27 16:00:02 117.79.149.2 GET 404 0 0",
   "2013-08-27 16:00:03 117.79.149.2 GET 200 0 0",
   "2013-08-27 16:00:04 117.79.149.2 GET 404 0 0"))

# With fixed width fields
mydf[, c("Date_Time", "Status")] <- list(substring(mydf$V1, 1, 19),
                                         substring(mydf$V1, 38, 40))


# or based on the delimiter " " which is closer from your trial ...
strings <- unlist(strsplit(as.character(mydf$V1), " "))
mydf[, c("Date_Time", "Status")] <- list(paste(strings[seq(1, length.out=nrow(mydf), by=7)], strings[seq(2, length.out=nrow(mydf), by=7)]), 
                                         strings[seq(5, length.out=nrow(mydf), by=7)])
```

Comment: Your answer might be more helpful to others if you make your code a little more readable.

Comment: @SESman,Thanks a lot! I think this method works on simple structure like the example I illustrate.Actually , every weblog record is more much complex and more fileds ,"substring" is not appropriate for that

Comment: Is there any more flexiable and efficient way instead of "substring"?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not familiar with your kind of data. `substring` and `strsplit` generally fit my needs. I would say that regular expressions are the most flexible tools but, beyond the basics, the syntax overheats my brain.

Comment: In the example you posted there is only one column delimiter (" ") so a `read.table` of the log file should be enough. Otherwise you can look to `scanf` and `fscannf` utilities that let you explain how to interpret each line, character after character . Unfortunately I don't know such a function in R (I use bash or matlab).