# How do I skip "#" sign without loop while extract elements?

Tags: r

I want to get a new data.frame from this data set,but there are some description with"#" between some rows and some rows contain "#" sign, I can use "for" loop under the conditon substr(x,1,1)!="#" and gsub() with regex to get the result I need, my problem is whether I can get the same result without "for" loop?

```
     1.#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
     2.#Version: 1.0
     3.#Fields: date time ip method stem query s-port username sc-substatus 
     4.2013-08-27 16:00:00 117.79.149.2 GET /images/tr.gif uid=936206260 200 0 0
     6.2013-08-27 16:00:01 117.79.149.2 GET /images/tr.gif referrer=#http://Ftrack 200 0 0     
     7.#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
     8.2013-08-27 16:00:02 117.79.149.2 GET /images/tr.gif uid=936206269 200 0 0
     9.2013-08-27 16:00:03 117.79.149.2 GET /images/tr.gif utm_medium#3Dc02#26utm 200 0 0
     10. ..........
     11. ..........
```

become this:

```
      V1                    V2
      2013-08-27 16:00:00   200
      2013-08-27 16:00:01   200
      2013-08-27 16:00:02   200
      2013-08-27 16:00:03   200
      ....................
      ....................
```

Comment: David, this question is still too vague, and not reproducible. We need more information. Specifically, make your input match your desired output. Make your example input contain any complexities that your real data does. And you need to specify if you're reading the table from an external file, or you already have it loaded into R.

Comment: @dayne,Hi daye,I have modify my example,my final goal is getting the data.frame with element "date_time" and "stauts" which I have made it with your help earlier.But there some description start with"#"sign,and some "#"sign in the some pieces of data as I illustrate,if I use comment.char="#",some data will be cut off so that I can't get status "200"

Comment: @dayne  Is there any efficient way without "for" loop to skip the row of description begin with "#" sign while I extract elements.

Comment: @dayne,dayne,would you help me to solve it?

Comment: What is the structure of your original dataset? Is it a vector? Or a one-column data frame?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein,Nice to see you again,it's a one-column data.frame after I input it by read.table()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the rows starting with `#` from your one-column data frame `x`:

```
vec <- grep("^[^#]", x[[1]], value = TRUE)
```

Then, create a new data frame based on the remaining data:

```
data.frame(V1 = gsub("(.*\\:[0-9]+) .*", "\\1", vec),
           V2 = gsub(".* ([0-9]+) [0-9]+ [0-9]+ *$", "\\1", vec))

#                    V1  V2
# 1 2013-08-27 16:00:00 200
# 2 2013-08-27 16:00:01 200
# 3 2013-08-27 16:00:02 200
# 4 2013-08-27 16:00:03 200
```

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you want to read the data from external table(it's unclear from your question), so accordingly i am answering your question,Use comment.char="#" in "read.table" option, it will ignore the lines starting with #.

See `?read.table`.

So, your first line could be:

```
x <- read.table("comm.txt",comment.char="#"),
```

where "comm.txt" is file which contains data according to your given format.

You can then use following code to split columns based on delimeter "-"

```
library(reshape2)
LS <- lapply(seq_along(x), function(i){
    colsplit(x[, i], "-", paste0(colnames(x)[i], letters[1:3]))
    }
)

do.call('cbind', LS)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `read.table("comm.txt",comment.char="#",sep="-")` No need to split the columns afterwards.

Comment: @plannapus,many thanks!Actually,icomment.char="#" doesn't work,because some rows contain "#" in my sepicifc dataset

Comment: @pradeep6kumar,I didn't describe my problem clearly and I have modify it.would you like help me to figure out a smart method?Thx in advance!

Comment: With this kind of data, I would personally remove the non important rows using regular expression using perl , vim or sed before bringing it to R.