# How to make read.table() in R ignore "#"

Tags: r, read.table

If i try this:

```
read.table("IntervalBasedReport (10).xls",dec=",",skip=20,fill=NA,sep="\t")
```

I get (Header of V6 is "#probes" and the rest of the line is not read in(i think)):

```
                                   V1    V2       V3          V4
1                        AberrationNo   Chr Cytoband       Start
2     US11113888_253174610065_S01_2_2                           
3                                   1  chr1   p36.13  16,348,612
4                                   2  chr2    q37.3 242,856,588
5                                   3  chr8    p11.1  43,371,449
6                                   4 chr14    q32.2 101,291,239
7                                   5  chrX   p11.23  48,323,343
8                                   6  chrX   p11.22  53,449,448
9         Number of calls per sample:                           
10 US11113888_253174610065_S01_2_2 =6                           
            V5  V6       V7        V8        V9
1         Stop  NA                             
2               NA                             
3   16,383,299  29 0.407738  0.000000 3.601e-22
4  243,007,359  29 0.000000 -0.793036 2.729e-77
5   43,381,512   4 0.755647  0.000000 1.770e-11
6  101,295,092  23 0.318718  0.000000 1.131e-11
7   48,760,198 121 0.250196  0.000000 7.654e-14
8   53,459,171  18 0.429467  0.000000 3.202e-10
9               NA                             
10              NA                             
                                                                                                                 V10
1                                                                                                                   
2                                                                                                                   
3                                                                                                     CLCNKA, CLCNKB
4                                                                                                                   
5                                                                                                                   
6                                                                                                               MEG3
7  SLC38A5, FTSJ1, PORCN, EBP, TBC1D25, RBM3, WDR13, WAS, SUV39H1, GLOD5, GATA1, HDAC6, ERAS, PCSK1N, TIMM17B, PQBP1
8                                                                                             SMC1A, RIBC1, HSD17B10
9                                                                                                                   
10
```

The actual problem is the error i get if i try to skip the seccond row by doing something like this:

```
read.table(file="IntervalBasedReport (10).xls",dec=",",skip=22,fill=NA,sep="\t",col.names=read.table("IntervalBasedReport (10).xls",skip=20,nrows=1,dec=",",sep="\t"))
Error in read.table(file = "IntervalBasedReport (10).xls", dec = ",",  : 
  more columns than column names
```

Collumns V7 and on have headers, which i would like to use.
Thank you a lot!

Comment: To be honest, i have problems to understand your question, but does it help to disable the interpretation of comment characters (which is `#` by default) by setting `read.table( ... , comment.char = "" )`? See `? read.table` for details.

Comment: this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093294/how-do-i-skip-sign-without-loop-while-extract-elements/20094929#20094929

Comment: Why are you trying to read an `xls` file with `read.table` ? I'm surprised you're getting anything useful at all.